# How to solve the function $\max \sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i \cdot \mu)$ with $\sum _{j=1}^b \mu_j = 1$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

$$
\max_{\mu} \sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i \cdot \mu)\qquad\text{with}\qquad \sum _{j=1}^b \mu_j = 1,\qquad  \mu_i \ge 0,\qquad  x_{ij} \ge 0
$$
The function is shown as above, where $x_i$ and $\mu$ are vectors. The $x_i$ is fixed, and  I need find the optimal $\mu$. I try to apply the Lagrange multiplier method, while get stuck.

For example, $x_1 = [0,0.1,0.2,0.7]$,$x_2 = [0.1,0,0.1,0.8]$,.. $\mu = [0,0,0.5,0.5]$

In addition, in my context, all $\sum_{j=1} x_{ij} = 1$. Though i think this condition is not necessary, it may convert the original question to other form. When all $x_i = [0,0,..1,0,0]$, i solved the $\mu_j = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij}$ using properties of information entropy.

Comment: Can you please clean up your model? (And please use LaTeX instead of an image.) The $\mu$ in the objective does not have a subscript; did you intend to say $\mu_i$ there? And the summations are over a different range ($k$ vs $n$); is that intentional? I am assuming that $0\leq \min_i x_i$ and $\sum_i x_i\neq 0$; is that correct?

Comment: $\mu$ and $x_i$ are  vectors $x_i \cdot \mu$ is dot product between vectors.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that $\mu_i\geq 0$ for all $i$. You can reformulate the problem as

$$
\max \sum_{i=1}^n \log( y_i )\\
s.t.\\
y_i = x_i\cdot \mu_i \quad i=1,\ldots,n\\
\sum_{j=1}^k \mu_i = 1\\
\mu_i \ge 0  \quad i=1,\ldots,n
$$

Assuming that $x_i$ are such that $y_i\geq 0$ for all $i$, this is a convex problem you can solve with a standard optimizer.

Comment: Does it have closed form solution?

Comment: Not likely, no.

Comment: If you replace the objective with $\left(\prod_{i=1}^n y_i\right)^{1/n}$, which obtains the same solution, you can convert this to a second-order cone problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a closed form solution for your problem under the following assumption:
$x_i > 0, \mu_i > 0 $, for all $i$.

You can rewrite $\sum_{i=1}^N \log(x_i \mu_i) = \log(\prod_{i=1}^N x_i \mu_i)$. Using this identity, it is clear that your problem is equivalent to
$$ \max   c \prod_{i=1}^N  \mu_i~~~{\rm s.t.}  ~~ \sum_{j=1}^N \mu_i = 1,$$
where $c = \prod_{i=1}^N  x_i$. The equivalence follows from the monotonicity of the logarithm, or, in other words, the logarithm is maximized if its argument is maximized.

The solution to the equivalent problem is given by $\mu_i = 1/N.$

Comment: note μ and $x_i$ are vectors. $x_i \cdot \mu$ is dot product between vectors. So you can not extract $x_i$

Comment: I see. Then, you can follow AC_MOSEK. He is right.